# use IonCube Loaders in Linux System

Tags: php, linux, encode, ioncube

Ioncube loader I have installed on my server in the directory / usr / local / IonCube is the ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so file and this set in php.ini, but I want to encrypt a .php file and have no idea how to use it I saw an example of encoded file and began: "if (extension_loaded ('ionCube Loader')!"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code so the community can help review it (you are more likely to get help if you show your efforts made prior to posting the question). Thank you. P.S.: Check out the [Question checklist](meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what's expected from a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ionCube Loader can only *load* encoded files. To actually produce ionCube encoded files you'll have to purchase the **ionCube PHP Encoder** ([see here](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)).

In addition, you can download the trial of the ionCube PHP Encoder [here](http://www.ioncube.com/encoder_eval_download.php).

If you have any specific questions regarding the ionCube PHP Encoder, you can contact ionCube's sales team, either by writing an email, via live chat or by opening a ticket at the [ionCube support HelpDesk](http://support.ioncube.com/).